# Grand staff with octave symbol using Ioctfinup

Tags: musixtex

It is needed to adjust the octave symbol of `Ioctfinup` command. I try it using: `\def\octnumberdown{\ppffsixteen8$_{ba}$}`, but it doesn't works. The basic code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=2.8cm, left=2.5cm, right=0.5cm, marginparwidth=0cm, marginparsep=0cm, headheight=13.6pt, a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

\usepackage{musixtex} 

\begin{document}
Grand staff with piano notes:
\vspace*{2.5cm}

\begin{music}
    \parindent10mm
    %\sepbarrules
    \instrumentnumber{2}
    \setstaffs1{1}
    \setstaffs2{1}
    \setclef20
    \setclef16
    \smallmusicsize
    \curlybrackets{12}
    \nobarnumbers
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% second fontsize, 4pt possible, too
    \startpiece%
    \notes\zcn{``B}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A A0}\wh{!`A}&\en
    \notes\zcn{``B}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B0}\wh{!`B}&\en
    \notes\zcn{``C}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A C1}\wh{!`C}&\en
    \notes\zcn{``C}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B1}\wh{!B}&\en
    \notes\zcn{``H}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A C2}\wh{!C}&\en
    \notes\zcn{``H}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B2}\wh{!I}&\en
    \notes\zcn{A}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A C3}\wh{!J}&\en
    \notes\zcn{A}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B3}\wh{!b}&\en
    \notes&\zcn{`c}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A C4}\wh{!c}\en
    \notes&\zcn{`c}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B4}\wh{!i}\en
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A C5}\wh{!j}\en
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B5}\wh{!p}\en
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A C6}\wh{!q}\en
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B6}\wh{!w}\en
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A C7}\wh{!x}\en
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B7}\Ioctfinup 1{''s}\wh{!w}\en
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A C8}\Toctfin1\wh{!x}\en
    \Endpiece
 \end{music}

\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

The desired output is as follow:
[image: desired]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which one do you want?

```
    \documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=2.8cm, left=2.5cm, right=0.5cm, marginparwidth=0cm, marginparsep=0cm, headheight=13.6pt, a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

\usepackage{musixtex} 

\begin{document}
Grand staff with piano notes:
\vspace*{2.5cm}

\begin{music}
    \parindent10mm
    %\sepbarrules
    \instrumentnumber{2}%
    \setstaffs1{1}%
    \setstaffs2{1}%
    \setclef20%
    \setclef16%
    \smallmusicsize%
    \curlybrackets{12}%
    \nobarnumbers%
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% second fontsize, 4pt possible, too
    \startpiece%
\notes\def\octnumberup{\ppffsixteen8$_{ba}$\addspace{-0.5em}}\octfinup{9}{5}\zcn{``B}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A A0}\wh{!`A}&\en%
    \notes\zcn{``B}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B0}\wh{!`B}&\en%
    \notes\zcn{``C}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A C1}\unbkt{`D}{1}{0}\wh{!`C}&\en%
  \notes\addspace{-0.5em}\def\octnumberdown{\ppffsixteen8$_{ba}$}\octfindown{-10}{3.3}\addspace{0.5em}\zcn{``C}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B1}\wh{!B}&\en%
    \notes\zcn{``H}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A C2}\wh{!C}&\en%
    \notes\zcn{``H}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B2}\wh{!I}&\en%
    \notes\zcn{A}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A C3}\wh{!J}&\en%
    \notes\zcn{A}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B3}\wh{!b}&\en%
    \notes&\zcn{`c}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A C4}\wh{!c}\en%
    \notes&\zcn{`c}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B4}\wh{!i}\en%
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A C5}\wh{!j}\en%
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B5}\wh{!p}\en%
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A C6}\wh{!q}\en%
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B6}\wh{!w}\en%
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A C7}\wh{!x}\en%
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A B7}\addspace{-0.5em}\def\octnumberup{\ppffsixteen8$^{va}$}\octfinup{20}{1.2}\addspace{0.5em}\wh{!w}\en%
    \notes&\zcn{`f}{\hspace*{-0.10cm}\bf\A C8}\wh{!x}\en%
    \Endpiece%
 \end{music}

\end{document}
```

The only thing I haven't found yet is a striped unbkt.
[image]

Comment: Great!!! octfinup is used inside bar measure, but when it is needed in different bars?

Comment: There is no problem. You only need to increase the length, because there will be an additional beforeruleskip and an afterruleskip. Try to put a bar after the first \en first and then see the difference with changing the length (last argument) from 5 to 6.